# regex not matching number correctly

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following regex: (\d{14}) decimal that matches 14 character long number. The problem is that it also matches numbers, that are 16 characters long. I need to add a condition to match **if there are no numbers at beginning or end of string**.

So for example 112222222222222233 wouldn't be a match i want, but xx22222222222222xx would be match I need.

Comment: `^\d{14})$` seems to work

Comment: What about `"x0xx00001111222234xx"`? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

M42's answer can work in cases where the number is delimited by spaces or other word delimiters. But if you want to match a number in a word containing non-digits (like your example `xx22222222222222xx`) something like this should work:

```
(^|[^\d])\d{14}([^\d]|$)
```

Answer (score 5):

use word boundary `\b`

```
\b\d{14}\b
```